# SyntaxError: Unexpected token `<` -- AngularJS Application is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am currently working Wcf service with MVC . I am trying to consume my wcf service by using AngularJS and MVC Framework.I am trying to do insert, update and delete using wcf with AngularJS and mvc . My wcf service is working nicely but when I run AngularJS Application in Google Chrome its does not display any data in website and i Can not do insert , update and delete operation. I launch the developer tools and it is showing following errors..

```
d.sitespeeds.com/:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:33671 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
angular.js:4957 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module RESTClientModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'RESTClientModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/nomod?p0=RESTClientModule
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:116:12
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:2297:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:2218:38)
    at module (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:2295:14)
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4933:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:410:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4917:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4839:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:1949:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:1970:12)

    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:116:12
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:2297:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:2218:38)
    at module (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:2295:14)
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4933:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:410:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4917:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4839:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:1949:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:1970:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:116:12
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4957:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:410:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4917:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:4839:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:1949:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:1970:12)
    at angularInit (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:1855:5)
    at http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:33826:5
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (http://localhost:50349/Scripts/angular.js:3468:5)
```

I also added the required AngularJS JavaScript Packages.Here is my AngularJS code for insert, update and delete operation . The wcf service is available on localhost under the pot number 50028. The name of the service is student service. The name of module is RESTClientModule and its registered with the controller.

```
 /// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  
   var app;
   (function () {
app = angular.module("RESTClientModule",  []); 

app.controller("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController", function ($scope, CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService) {

    $scope.OperType = 1;
    //1 Mean New Entry  

    GetAllRecords();
    //To Get All Records  
    function GetAllRecords() {
        var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllStudent();
        promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Students = pl.data },
            function (errorPl) {
                $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
            });
    }

    //To Clear all input controls.  
    function ClearModels() {
        $scope.OperType = 1;
        $scope.StudentID = "";
        $scope.Name = "";
        $scope.Email = "";
        $scope.Class = "";
        $scope.EnrollYear = "";
        $scope.City = "";
        $scope.Country = "";
    }

    //To Create new record and Edit an existing Record.  
    $scope.save = function () {
        var Student = {
            Name: $scope.Name,
            Email: $scope.Email,
            Class: $scope.Class,
            EnrollYear: $scope.EnrollYear,
            City: $scope.City,
            Country: $scope.Country
        };
        if ($scope.OperType === 1) {
            var promisePost = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.post(Student);
            promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                $scope.StudentID = pl.data.StudentID;
                GetAllRecords();

                ClearModels();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
            });
        } else {
            //Edit the record      
            debugger;
            Student.StudentID = $scope.StudentID;
            var promisePut = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.put($scope.StudentID, Student);
            promisePut.then(function (pl) {
                $scope.Message = "Student Updated Successfuly";
                GetAllRecords();
                ClearModels();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
            });
        }
    };

    //To Get Student Detail on the Base of Student ID  
    $scope.get = function (Student) {
        var promiseGetSingle = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.get(Student.StudentID);
        promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
            var res = pl.data;
            $scope.StudentID = res.StudentID;
            $scope.Name = res.Name;
            $scope.Email = res.Email;
            $scope.Class = res.Class;
            $scope.EnrollYear = res.EnrollYear;
            $scope.City = res.City;
            $scope.Country = res.Country;
            $scope.OperType = 0;
        },
            function (errorPl) {
                console.log('Some Error in Getting Details', errorPl);
            });
    }

    //To Delete Record  
    $scope.delete = function (Student) {
        var promiseDelete = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.delete(Student.StudentID);
        promiseDelete.then(function (pl) {
            $scope.Message = "Student Deleted Successfuly";
            GetAllRecords();
            ClearModels();
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
        });
    }
});

app.service("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService", function ($http) {
    //Create new record  
    this.post = function (Student) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/AddNewStudent",
            data: Student
        });
        return request;
    }

    //Update the Record  
    this.put = function (StudentID, Student) {
        debugger;
        var request = $http({
            method: "put",
            url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/UpdateStudent",
            data: Student
        });
        return request;
    }

    this.getAllStudent = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent");
    };

    //Get Single Records  
    this.get = function (StudentID) {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetStudentDetails/" + StudentID);
    }

    //Delete the Record  
    this.delete = function (StudentID) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "delete",
            url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/DeleteStudent/" + StudentID
        });
        return request;
    }

});
```

});

Here is HTML Code....

```
    <html data-ng-app="RESTClientModule">
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Student Information using AngularJs, WCF REST &   MVC4";
}
<body>
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">
                    <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="stud in Students">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.StudentID}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Name}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Email}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Class}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.EnrollYear}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.City}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Country}}</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="get(stud)" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Delete" value="Delete" data-ng-click="delete(stud)" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Student ID</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="StudentID" readonly="readonly" data-ng-model="StudentID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Student Name</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sName" required data-ng-model="Name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Email</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sEmail" required data-ng-model="Email" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Class</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sClass" required data-ng-model="Class" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Enrollement Year</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sEnrollYear" required data-ng-model="EnrollYear" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>City</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sCity" required data-ng-model="City" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Country</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sCountry" required data-ng-model="Country" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" data-ng-click="save()" />

                            <input type="button" id="Clear" value="Clear" data-ng-click="clear()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
 <script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Modules.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the Controller

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    // GET: Student
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

There is BundleConfig

```
  public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

}

Here is the screen shot When i run the Application ...
[image: Please click here to see the out put]

Comment: Remove `<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>` because you already have `<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>` which causes angular to be loaded more than once. Also, load `angularjs` inside the `head` tag before the body.

Comment: @Ephraim i did remove it but still it is showing this error?o=3&g=EC0825C4-90A4-2692-D257-CD2C2B565912&s=1A2C77E8-0498-4A11-B8B8-D740DBEC71C4&z=1403834305:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @Ephraim Thank you very much your suggestion

Comment: Is this page a partial view?  I noticed the `Application Name` and bootstrap menu on the upper right which is not in your html source code. If so, you shouldn't have an html tag inside your outer html tag. If you have a `_Layout.cshtml` then you better load angular there instead.

Comment: @Ephraim What i did I created controller and named it Index then i added view and edited it

Comment: Then you do have a layout cshtml. I suggest you first read [this guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par) before trying to combine both ASP.NET MVC and ANGULARJS if you are not yet familiar with how both MVC and angular works.

Comment: I will do it Please tell me what is the solution of this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't load your application correctly.

If `<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Modules.js"></script>` contains your `RESTClientModule` then you should load your scripts like this inside the `<head/>` tag.

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Modules.js"></script>
</head>
```

Always load your modules after loading the angular library.

EDIT:

Here is how I resolved your issue.

- Removed the call to `_Layout.cshtml` inside `_ViewStart.cshtml`
- Added `angular.min.js` and `Modules.js` inside the `<head></head>` tag
- Load `angular.min.js` before `Modules.js`

Modules.js

```
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  
var app;

(function () {
    app = angular.module("RESTClientModule",  []); 

    app.controller("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController", function ($scope, CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;
        //1 Mean New Entry  

        GetAllRecords();
        //To Get All Records  
        function GetAllRecords() {
            var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllStudent();
            promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Students = pl.data },
                function (errorPl) {
                    $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
                });
        }

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.StudentID = "";
            $scope.Name = "";
            $scope.Email = "";
            $scope.Class = "";
            $scope.EnrollYear = "";
            $scope.City = "";
            $scope.Country = "";
        }

        //To Create new record and Edit an existing Record.  
        $scope.save = function () {
            var Student = {
                Name: $scope.Name,
                Email: $scope.Email,
                Class: $scope.Class,
                EnrollYear: $scope.EnrollYear,
                City: $scope.City,
                Country: $scope.Country
            };
            if ($scope.OperType === 1) {
                var promisePost = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.post(Student);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.StudentID = pl.data.StudentID;
                    GetAllRecords();

                    ClearModels();
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                });
            } else {
                //Edit the record      
                debugger;
                Student.StudentID = $scope.StudentID;
                var promisePut = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.put($scope.StudentID, Student);
                promisePut.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.Message = "Student Updated Successfuly";
                    GetAllRecords();
                    ClearModels();
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
                });
            }
        };

        //To Get Student Detail on the Base of Student ID  
        $scope.get = function (Student) {
            var promiseGetSingle = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.get(Student.StudentID);
            promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
                var res = pl.data;
                $scope.StudentID = res.StudentID;
                $scope.Name = res.Name;
                $scope.Email = res.Email;
                $scope.Class = res.Class;
                $scope.EnrollYear = res.EnrollYear;
                $scope.City = res.City;
                $scope.Country = res.Country;
                $scope.OperType = 0;
            },
                function (errorPl) {
                    console.log('Some Error in Getting Details', errorPl);
                });
        }

        //To Delete Record  
        $scope.delete = function (Student) {
            var promiseDelete = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.delete(Student.StudentID);
            promiseDelete.then(function (pl) {
                $scope.Message = "Student Deleted Successfuly";
                GetAllRecords();
                ClearModels();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
            });
        }
    });

    app.service("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService", function ($http) {
        //Create new record  
        this.post = function (Student) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/AddNewStudent",
                data: Student
            });
            return request;
        }

        //Update the Record  
        this.put = function (StudentID, Student) {
            debugger;
            var request = $http({
                method: "put",
                url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/UpdateStudent",
                data: Student
            });
            return request;
        }

        this.getAllStudent = function () {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent");
        };

        //Get Single Records  
        this.get = function (StudentID) {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetStudentDetails/" + StudentID);
        }

        //Delete the Record  
        this.delete = function (StudentID) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "delete",
                url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/DeleteStudent/" + StudentID
            });
            return request;
        }

    });

})();
```

Index.cshtml / Main View

```
<html data-ng-app="RESTClientModule">
<head title="ASAS">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Modules.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">
                    <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="stud in Students">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.StudentID}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Name}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Email}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Class}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.EnrollYear}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.City}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Country}}</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="get(stud)" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Delete" value="Delete" data-ng-click="delete(stud)" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Student ID</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="StudentID" readonly="readonly" data-ng-model="StudentID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Student Name</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sName" required data-ng-model="Name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Email</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sEmail" required data-ng-model="Email" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Class</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sClass" required data-ng-model="Class" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Enrollement Year</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sEnrollYear" required data-ng-model="EnrollYear" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>City</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sCity" required data-ng-model="City" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Country</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sCountry" required data-ng-model="Country" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" data-ng-click="save()" />
                            <input type="button" id="Clear" value="Clear" data-ng-click="clear()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;//"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Output:

[image]

P.S. Try to understand first the components of ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS independently before trying to merge the two.

Comment: I did not added HTML Page I just add the view from Controller

Comment: @Rasel I said that because there is an `<html data-ng-app="RESTClientModule">` tag on your sample code but clearly there is no **Application Name** and menu (based on screen shot) which is supposedly residing in `\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` and this is set inside `\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml`. Your bundles are fine, it has nothing to do with angular unless you're loading angular through a bundle.

Comment: I am really sorry after remove every error its showing following error again Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Thanks I got same result when I run the application but I can not do insert update and delete when I click save button its showing this errors Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
2:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Index:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent. No 'Access-